# Why django urls end with a slash?

Tags: python, django

Django official documentation and other tutorials on the web always use a trailing slash at the end of url. ex:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/', views.login)  # login view in turn calls login.html

# instead of

url(r'^accounts/login', views.login)
```

Since `accounts` is the directory and `login (login.html)` is the file, shouldn't we be using second url? This will also make `GET` parameters look more structured:

```
accounts/login?name='abc'  # login is a file that is accepting parameters
vs.
accounts/login/?name='abc' # login directory (maybe index) is accepting parameters??
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One of Django’s [core design philosophies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/) is **URLs should be beautiful.**

So some url like **`accounts/detail?name='abc'`** should be mapped as **`accounts/detail/abc/`**. You can capture it using regex at your url configurations. Here the URL is pretty neat and user friendly. This will help the search engines to index your pages correctly (now you can forget about `rel=canonical`) and will help in seo.

Now the reason for a trailing slash, consider a view (in any framework) which  relatively resolves **`about.html`** for a user at path, **`users/awesomeUser`**

since `users/awesomeUser` and `users/awesomeUser/` are different,

1. If the user is at `users/awesomeUser`, the browser will resolve it as `users/about.html` because there ain't a trailing slash which we don't want
2. If the user is at `users/awesomeUser/`, the browser will resolve it as `users/awesomeUser/about.html` because there is a trailing slash

> - `child` relative to `family/parent/` is `family/parent/child`.
> - `child` relative to `family/parent` is `family/child`.

#### [Django Design philosophy on Definitive URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#definitive-urls) reads,

> Technically, **foo.com/bar** and **foo.com/bar/** are two different URLs, and search-engine robots (and some Web traffic-analyzing tools) would treat them as separate pages. Django should make an effort to “normalize” URLs so that search-engine robots don’t get confused.
>
> **This is the reasoning behind the APPEND_SLASH setting.** (APPEND_SLASH lets you force append slashes to a URL)

## Still not convinced?

1. Since django observes both the urls as different, if you are caching your app, Django will keep two copies for same page at `user/awesomeUser` and `user/awesomeUser/`.
2. You gotta have issues with HTTP methods other than GET if you don't append slash to a URL (If you ever plan to build a REST API).

### Update

You can't make POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE methods to work with `rest_framework` unless you explicitly define `APPEND_SLASH=False` in settings and `trailing_slash=False` for each and every router you gotta use(if you use Routers). *It is like you basically gonna skip this most times* and you gotta waste a hell lot of time debugging this. Django recommends `append slashes` and doesn't force it.

Its up to the developer to append slashes or not.

Comment: This answer explains the difference of with and without trailing slash in terms of how a browser will resolve their child links. But it does not explain why Django chooses one specific way over the other. I don't know the answer either, but, so far it seems a random choice at the beginning. It could go the other way since day 1, and those URLs would still be "definitive" as long as they stick to one form. So, to me, this seems like those coding-style thing, i.e. there is no definite right and wrong, there is just convention.

Comment: I'm glad Django doesn't enforce this rule and it shouldn't, because it will cause hell for those that may be working with multiple backends that are using urls without trailing slashes, or at the very least you would have to reconfigure the http server's reverse proxy to handle this matter

Answer (score 5):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware) for the middleware that uses `APPEND_SLASH`

> a search-engine indexer would treat them as separate URLs – so it’s best practice to normalize URLs.

Its not required by django, its just trying to help your SEO by suggesting a standard way of doing urls.

<sub>Yes, I know that the slash has nothing to do with this middleware but this is the best explanation I could find as to a possible reason</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but we generally use `rel=canonical` in the html pages to let search engine know which link to index

Comment: @TheWanderer - Of course, SEO isn't something that django goes into much detail about in the docs but instead it tries to instill a standard format  for urls straight from the tutorial

Answer (score 2):

"URLs should be beautiful"!!!
I want to be able to control URLs. It's nothing nice when everything is about to be overwritten. Under circumstances, I make a redirect loop which is not funny.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect as rdrct

url(r'^sitemap.xml$', 'my_app.views.custom_sm'),

url(r'^sitemap.xml/$', lambda x: rdrct('/sitemap.xml')),
```

Comment: Have you slash after xml?

Answer (score 1):

This helps define the structure of your website. Although django can support anything entered after the domain that is passed to the server doing it in this way allows you to easily add "subpages" to the url without it looking like `accounts/loginreset?id=alkfjahgouasfjvn25jk1k25`

That being said in the case above it may make sense to leave it out.