# Static files being referenced via different path in same Django view

Tags: django, static, urlconf

I recently updated one of my views and URLs to take an additional parameter and now that I have done this the page which is rendered displays with no css or javascript because the static path is wrong.

I am obviously not understanding correctly how static is served however I didn't think that changing the URL confs would change the path that Django would look for static.  All my static for the whole site is in the one place.

urls.py

```
url(r'^fill/(.*)/(.*)/$', views.fill_survey, name='unique_getfile'),
url(r'^fill/(.*)', views.fill_survey, name='unique_getfile'),
```

and here is my view ... first block executes for the first url match and the second block executes for the bottom url

```
def fill_survey(request, unique_url, new_name="blank"):
    """
    get file or redirect to error page
    """
    if len(unique_url) < 50:
        if unique_url == "new":
            firstlast = new_name.split(" ")
            c = Client.objects.get(firstname=firstlast[0], lastname=firstlast[1])
            survey_url_number = generate_survey(request, c.email)
            response = Survey.objects.get(number=survey_url_number['number'])
            return render(request, 'survey/survey.html', {'survey': response})
        else:
            response = Survey.objects.get(number=unique_url)
            return render(request, 'survey/survey.html', {'survey': response})
```

The rendered page then has the following static paths for the first and second url match respectively:

```
wwww.mysite.com/static/etc...
www.mysite.com/module_name/static/etc...
```

Paths in my template like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../static/classic/global/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Why are these different URLs leading to different static paths?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the relevant docs but by default Django only looks for static resources in `/static/` folder or its subfolders. You can define a list of static file directories in your settings file if you want though.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

EDIT: Response to comment.
Can I see your template? Also, I'd try changing all your urls to end in a `/$`.

EDIT: Response to posted template.
I use the static tag rather than the absolute. I.E.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "/css/bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css" %}">`

This way if we mess with the location of our templates we don't ned to go back and change all the templates
.

A couple thought about your html:

- Since it doesn't start with `/` it's pointing to the a folder within the current folder.
- With a `/` it points to the path at the root of your current web.
  See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Regarding why I end my addresses in `/$`. Here's a good answer.
[Why django urls end with a slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212122/why-django-urls-end-with-a-slash)

I wish I had a clearer answer for you but try the trailing `/` in the url and the leading `/` or `{% static %}` in your template.

Comment: Hi Harry thanks for your reply... my files are in my static folder but the problem is that for the second URL is referencing website.com/module_name/static rather than just website.com/static  like the first one ... why is it looking for the static files at a different path if its the same view?

Comment: Thank you will do $ (can I ask why this is necessary, is it a safety consideration?) and have added to my original post how I am referencing files in my template which I assume is what you are after?