# To put or not to put slash ("/") at the end of each url path

Tags: django

I know that using formerly url() there is a difference whether or not I put slash ("/") at the end of a sentence i.e.

```
url(r'^fees_pricer/(?P<product>[\w-]+)/$', views.fees_pricer, name='fees_pricer'),
```

I realized that I got the same result if I write:

```
path('fees_pricer/<slug:prod>', views.fees_pricer, name='fees_pricer'),
```

or

```
path('fees_pricer/<slug:prod>/', views.fees_pricer, name='fees_pricer'),
```

I am wondering if there is a difference or any best practice about putting shlash at the end of each path.
Many thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212122/why-django-urls-end-with-a-slash

Comment: May be I did not ask correctly the question but I saw your duplicate but my question is more about path() than url().

Comment: Django 2 introduces `path()` as a replacement for `url()` to define app urls.

Comment: And path() doesn't bring any new functionalities (Apart the regex) compared to url() ?

Answer (score 2):

The general Django practice is to have slash-terminated routes (and there's even the `CommonMiddleware`-powered option `APPEND_SLASH` to try and ensure it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what APPEND_SLASH option does exactly?