# can anyone explain why this is giving error django url patterns

Tags: django

```
urlpatterns=
[path(r"<int:id>", ThreadView.as_view(),name="thread-view"),]
```

why this is giving an error.If I put

```
r"<int:id>/"
```

It is not giving error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212122/why-django-urls-end-with-a-slash

Comment: You haven't said what the error is when the slash is missing.